# what is space complexity for this program?

Tags: c, algorithm

This is just a test function for calculating space complexity if we consider the 
number of  stack frames  than it will be o(n) but what about those arrays a and b inside  `for` loop and 2-d which will also take some memory  in every recursive call,my professor told us that space complexity is size of stack frame but it also consuming some space in that for loop also 
Should i consider both that is stack frame and two arrays  and 2-d array or give any one of them priority and why?

> I am just focusing on space complexity so forget about the result or garbage collection

```
testfun(n){
  if(n==0)
  return;
  int c[10][10];
  int *a=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
  int *b=malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {  a[i]=n+2*i;
     b[i]=n+3*i;
  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
     {
        c[i][j]=1;
     }
  testfun(n-1);
  free(a);
  free(b); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space complexity of above program is `O(n^2)+O(n)` `O(n^2)` for 2-d matrix and `O(n)`
for 1-d array

Answer (score 1):

The space complexity of the question is O(n)if you have freed the memory locations before call to the function, since each call to the function needs to remember the stack variables.

```
free(a);
free(b);
test(n - 1);
```

Else in each function call the function allocates O(n) space and same in subsequent recursive calls as well. So space complexity is O(n^2).

Using Substitution method:

```
S(0) = 0
S(n) = S(n - 1) + 2n                 -------- (1)
S(n - 1) = S(n - 2) + 2 (n - 1)      -------- (2)
S(n - 2) = S(n - 3) + 2 (n - 2)      -------- (3)
```

Using (1), (2), (3)

```
S(n) = S(n - 1) + 2n
S(n) = S(n - 2) + 2 (n - 1) + 2n
S(n) = S(n - 3) + 2(n - 2) + 2(n - 1) + 2n
 .
 .
 .
 .
S(n) = S(n - k) + 2(n - (k - 1)) + ... + 2n

Let k = n

S(n) = S(n - n) + 2(1) + 2(2) + ... 2(n)
S(n) = S(0) + 2(n * (n + 1)) / 2
S(n) = 0 + n^2 + n
```

Therefore space complexity is O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

It might be you think about the `free` function. But, recursion is happened before theese `free` function. Hence, in each call of the function, depends on the value of the input (`i`), size of the allocated space is `2i`. As the stopping time is on `n == 0`, the total space complexity is `sum_{i = 1}^{n} 2*i  = 2*n(n+1)/2 = \Theta(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The space complexity of above program is `O(n^2).`
The reason for this is the `a and b` are of size n and hence both of them have a space complexity of `O(2n)` which is nothing but `O(n)`.
Now the recursion is simply from `n to 1` and each recursion call consumes `O(n)` space. Therefore space complexity will be `O(n^2).`

Comment: Now i have modified the question what would be the space complexity?

Comment: @Alishachaudhary The space complexity won't change since `c` contains 10×10 elements only which is nothing but a constant O(1).

Comment: do you want to say something like this
To conclude, space complexity of recursive algorithm is proportinal to maximum depth of recursion tree generated. If each function call of recursive algorithm takes O(m) space and if the maximum depth of recursion tree is 'n' then space complexity of recursive algorithm would be O(nm).